# JDBC identify getUpdateCount() is update or insert or delete

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

The Statement has `getUpdateCount()` method but how can I identify it is a update or insert or delete operation?

Comment: How come you don't already know?

Comment: I write an app that user input sql string and execute that
I want to identify the sql is a query or update operation for granting permission for each user, too.

Comment: So why do you need to know? If its just for the user tell him 'N rows affected' like all the other SQL command line processors do.

Comment: No, The oracle client show explicitly insert or update rows

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original `Statement` from the `ResultSet` by using [resultSetInstance.getStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)(), cast it to a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), whose toString() method spits out the original statement as a [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). From here, it's just checking the statement itself.

Comment: do you mean parse the sql String for detecting the "update", "delete" tokens?
I want a jdbc supporting method, not parsing sql string

Comment: I wish you the best of luck, I don't know of such a method.

Comment: Not every JDBC driver implements a proper Statement.toString() method.

Comment: Which is why one needs to cast, @EJP

Comment: @hd1 No it isn't. This is complete nonsense. Casting has zero effect on which toString() method is called. You don't seem to know much about it.

Comment: @EJP There are good and bad ways to correct. If my answer is *complete nonsense*, provide the right one. That's the good way. What you did with your answer was complete poppycock. If you read my other answers, you'll notice that I have been abused here before and let it slide. Fix the problem with your comment, don't try to make me the issue.